# different positioning chrome and firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have something like this:

html:

```
<span class="st">sometext >
<ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
</ul>

</span>
```

css:

```
.st{
    position:relative;
}


.st:hover ul{
    transition: opacity 1s;
    opacity:1;  
}

.st ul{
    margin:0;
    padding-left:5%;
    opacity:0;
    position:absolute;
    width:8em;
    top:0;
    left:100%;
    list-style: none outside none;
}

.st ul li{
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;

}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qLuw2/)

--> the list (some images with links, but simplified to letters here) shows up when hovering over someText. In firefox it shows up right next to someText > (which is the desired outcome), in Chrome however it appears much further right.

My initial guess was that (since the ul is nested in the span) the width of the span is calculated differently, that firefox ignores the opacity 0 list for calculating the width of the span and chrome uses it. But I have the same issue when removing the opacity rules and using display: none/block for hiding and showing of the ul.
(note: I say chrome, but I'm actually using Chromium 31.0.1650.63 on Ubuntu in case that makes a difference)
--> Any idea what causes this? And how can I solve this?

Comment: it was just to give it some more space, I don't know why I never checked that. I guess it makes more sense to use a higher value for left instead. Post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So.. why does the `.st ul` have `padding-left:5%;`? Because it seems that's what's causing it.

Plus you're placing **block** stuff (`ul`) inside **inline** element (`span`), so another reason not to be surprised with different (that is, *undefined*) behaviour.

Comment: but why does it make such a big difference? I'm using em to define the width of the ul, so it just about different default font-size?

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I think you have to reset browsers defaults. 
Try to use [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) or an simple [css reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

Comment: I am using a reset in the project, but it doesn't change things.

Answer (score 0):

I never was a big fan of the list elements.
They seem to act slightly differently in all browsers, including their default margins and paddings.

Why not use a simple div element instead? You can do whatever you want with it.

Also you might want to use & gt; instead of > because it is a special html tag and might ruin the code (though browsers are smart enough these days).

http://jsfiddle.net/qLuw2/9/

```
<span class="st">sometext &gt;
<div class="hoverable">
    a <br />
    b <br />
    c
</div>

</span>
```

Comment: you are right about the &gt; I'm actually using it, but was lazy in the fiddle. Otherwise, I like to use lists. If you looked a bit closer at the css or the fiddle you would have seen that I'm using a horizonatal list, so no need for those ugly br's. I might actually try using a nested span instead of a list